# Как стили с одной строки перенести в колонку (как положено)

Tags: css

Здравствуйте!

Есть style.css

[Скачать](http://file1.uafile.com/510489)

Сюда код не стал помещать так как не вмещается. Там код в стилях идёт тупо в ряд, как сделать нормальный человеческий вид чтобы всё шло вниз как положено?

Comment: Это шутка? Что за отстойный файлообменник? Вы про gdisk и Dropbox ничего не слышали? И что мешает привести несколько строчек из вашего супер файла в вопросе? Все станет понятно без ссылок.

Comment: Вот результат: https://jsfiddle.net/r7x5f97w/

Comment: @KAGG Design первый какой попался в поисковике. Тебя кто-то заставляет скачивать от туда? Не нравится - пройди мимо.

Comment: Я проголосовал за закрытие вопроса, поскольку он не отвечает правилам сообщества. Почитайте про самодостаточный пример. Кроме того, подобное предложение по скачиванию файла из такого места говорит о том, что вы не цените время людей, отвечающих тут на вопросы.

Comment: да любой редактор кода имеет плагин, которым можно все выровнять с течении секунды...  например в sublime text 3 плагин  html-css-js-Prettify   https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify  он тебе и html и css и JS отформатирует ))))

Comment: На крайний случай, можно использовать консоль разработчика и скопировать потом код оттуда

Comment: а можно и сюда все слить (редактор) и нажать править)))))), только вспомнил...

Comment: Шелест Роман,  http://file1.uafile.com/311030  скачай свой файл

Answer (score 1):

любой unminified сервис. К примеру - https://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/
вставляете свой код и получаете expanded версию